# I want this program to loop but it is not looping

Tags: loops, python-3.x

```
from random import *
print("ROCK(0) \t PAPER(1) \t SCISSORS(2)") 
choice = eval(input("Enter your choice: "))
count = 0
if (choice == 0):
    print("You chose ROCK")
elif (choice == 1):
    print("You chose PAPER")
elif (choice == 2):
    print("You chose SCISSORS")

choice1 = randint(0,2)
if (choice1 == 0):
    print("The computer chose ROCK")
elif (choice1 == 1):
    print("The computer chose PAPER")
elif (choice1 == 2):
    print("The computer chose SCISSORS")

while count <= 3 and choice == 0:
    if choice1 == 0:
        print("Draw")
    if choice1 == 1:
        print("You Lose")
    if choice1 == 2:
        print("You Win") 
    count += 1
    print("ROCK(0) \t PAPER(1) \t SCISSORS(2)") 
    choice = eval(input("Enter your choice: "))
while count <= 3 and choice == 1:
    if choice1 == 0:
        print("You Win")
    if choice1 == 1:
        print("Draw")
    if choice1 == 2:
        print("You Lose")
    count += 1
    print("ROCK(0) \t PAPER(1) \t SCISSORS(2)") 
    choice = eval(input("Enter your choice: "))

while count <= 3 and choice == 2:
    if choice1 == 0:
        print("You Lose")
    if choice1 == 1:
        print("You Win")
    if choice1 == 2:
        print("Draw")
    count += 1
    print("ROCK(0) \t PAPER(1) \t SCISSORS(2)") 
    choice = eval(input("Enter your choice: "))
```

I want this program to loop 3 times but it is not so can you please help. I have added all the needed loop contents and I tried shifting the codes and everything and it still wouldnt work, so can you plese help

Comment: Why would it loop three times if the `choice` varies from its previous value. And assuming the choice value do not change, then also it will loop four times and not three because of the condition `count <= 3`

Comment: can u help me out with it

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
from random import *


REPEAT = 3

count = 0

for _ in range(REPEAT):
    print("ROCK(0) \t PAPER(1) \t SCISSORS(2)") 
    choice = eval(input("Enter your choice: "))

    if (choice == 0):
        print("You chose ROCK")
    elif (choice == 1):
        print("You chose PAPER")
    elif (choice == 2):
        print("You chose SCISSORS")

    choice1 = randint(0,2)
    if (choice1 == 0):
        print("The computer chose ROCK")
    elif (choice1 == 1):
        print("The computer chose PAPER")
    elif (choice1 == 2):
        print("The computer chose SCISSORS")

    if choice1 == 0:
        print("this round: Draw")
    elif choice1 == 1:
        print("this round: You Lose")
    elif choice1 == 2:
        print("this round: You Win") 
        count += 1


if count == 0:
    print("game: You Lose")
elif count == 2:
    print("game: You Win")
elif count == 1:
    print("game: Draw")
```